# All of my modules are not showing in administrator panel while migrated from 1.5.26 to joomla 2.5.8

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I've upgrade my joomla version 1.5.26 to joomla version 2.5.4 and all the things has been upgraded successfully. So when i goes into my joomla module manager admin panel then it is not showing me any kinds of modules which was previously visible in my old version(1.5.26) but in my frontend panel it can be seen easily.Does anyone knows the solution how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you said you migrated, I assume you used an extension such as jUpgrade.

Migrating will update the core file and database tables and thus should show all the core Joomla modules in the Module Manager, however it does not upgrade your 3rd party extensions, therefore you will need to download the Joomla 2.5 compatible versions. This upgrade however, should be showing your core modules in the list.

I hope you took a backup of your 1.5 site. If you did, trying running the upgrade again and if you didn't use jUpgrade, I suggest you do so.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have migrated my website through jupgrade extensions.

Comment: and it is literally showing nothing in the Module Manager? not even 1 module? Have you checked your error log? Try running the upgrade again.

Comment: It is showing some other modules but not all. I think that it might be occured due to the installation of the newly template named Bt Arise but i'm not sure if it's the one causing or not. Yup, i'm doing migrating again to find what it is the main problem behind of it

Comment: it wont be the template causing the problem. can you provide a screenshot of your module manager please?

Comment: HMM, well now i got it what's wrong. I misunderstood it as when jupgrade migrated into higher version then it converted my left, right and other position into joomla 2.5 position according and if i'm not wrong then i must have to install the 3rd party extensions again and it won't override the database table isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're using the standard template for joomla. Go to module manager, choose Administrator in the first filter, and see if all modules are published in actual module positions (i.e. cpanel, status, footer, icon, login, menu, submenu, toolbar I guess that's it for administrator)

Comment: HMM, well now i got it what's wrong. I misunderstood it as when jupgrade migrated into higher version then it converted my left, right and other position into joomla 2.5 position according and if i'm not wrong then i must have to install the 3rd party extensions again and it won't override the database table isn't it?

Comment: No, for modules you just need to go and put them in the posiions you want. Coming from 1.5 also make sure you are using an appropriate access level for your modules.
JUpgrade has no idea what template you are using or were using, so there is no way in the world it could reassign module positions. That needs to be custom for a site.  It just moves your data.